# CSS Sprite Button

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

These Sprite buttons are driving me bonkers. I can almost get them to work, but not quite.

I'm playing with this very simple sprite image:

[image: jp2Rollover Sprite]

I've got a jsfiddle project [>> HERE <<](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/PZh9F/1/) if you want to see that, but the code is below if you just want to look at it.

For my CSS, I have the following:

```
#menu {
  left:10px;
  top:50px;
  height:300px;
  width: 147px;
  position:fixed;
}
.sprite {
  background: url('http://www.jp2code.net/logos/jp2Rollover.png') 0px -100px no-repeat;
  height:50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width:147px;
  z-index:1;
}
.sprite a {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  color:Red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.sprite a:hover {
  background-position: 0px -50px;
  color:Yellow;
}
​
```

With that, my HTML is simple and small:

```
<html>
<body>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="sprite">You Are Here</li>
    <li class="sprite"><a href="#A">Contact</li>
    <li class="sprite"><a href="#B">Projects</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>​
```

I can't seem to get my active link image (at position 0) or my hover link image (at position 50) to show.

Also, I'd like to find a way to make the entire rectangular region (50 x 147) the hyperlink.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want to get: http://jsfiddle.net/PZh9F/37/ ?

CSS:

```
#menu { left:10px; top:50px; height:300px; width: 147px; position:fixed; }
.sprite { background: url('http://www.jp2code.net/logos/jp2Rollover.png') 0px -100px no-repeat; height:50px; padding-left: 50px; width:147px; z-index:1; }
.sprite a { background-position: 0px 100px; color:Red; vertical-align: middle; }
.sprite.current { background-position: 0px 0px; }
.sprite:hover { background-position: 0px -50px; }
.sprite:hover a { color:Yellow; }
```

And HTML:
  ​

```
<html>
<body>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="sprite current">You Are Here</li>
    <li class="sprite"><a href="#A">Contact</li>
    <li class="sprite"><a href="#B">Projects</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Ooh! Just about. "You are here" should be the dead link, though (bottom Sprite). I'm going to look at what you did now...

Comment: @jp2code I have updated link in my comment. Hopefully, now everything is as needed.

Comment: Apparently, it matters how I specify the tags and I can't (should not) use the Negative values for my initial position. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PZh9F/12/

As you ha set the background of the ul (as it should) you also need to change the backgorund position of this same `ul` on hover, so not for the `a` as you did. Change the text color however should be done with `a:hover` I hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying `background` to `<li>` tags and `background-position` to `<a>` tags instead of applying both to the same set of tags.

Answer (score 1):

you defined the background for li.sprite not the hyperlink . that's why when a:hover happens there is no background to go -50px down .

```
.sprite a {
   background-image: url('http://www.jp2code.net/logos/jp2Rollover.png');
   background-position: 0px -100px;
   color:Red;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display:block;
   width:147px;
   height:50px;
  }
.sprite a:hover {

   background-position: 0px -50px;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

background-positions by y-axis should have negative values of -50px and -100px.

Answer (score 1):

just a few issues:

The anchor tags weren't closed, so that may have caused some issues.

Any time you want something to behave like a link, it should use an anchor tag; I noticed the first li tag was just text. Technically, you can still achieve the same effect, but I'm guessing you're attempting to link to something.

When you're using html text for links within a button that is using a background image, I recommend putting the text into a span which makes it easier to format. When you add padding to an anchor tag without using the span, you can get extra padding on the opposite end in some browsers even with a set width. Just a little trick I learned over the years.

When using sprites, make sure you add height, width and display:block properties to the "a" selector. This will ensure that the entire link is clickable.

It looks like some of your hovers are jumping, it might be an issue with your sprite. It's crucial that your measurements are accurate. If it's even 1px off it can produce an undesired flicker effect.

The complete code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PZh9F/65/

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm after. The version you just posted (#65) has the 2nd image (@50px) displayed in the "You Are Here" section instead of the 1st image (@0px). Is there a way you can see to make the "You Are Here" section the dark gray and not act like a hyperlink?

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't want it to act as a hyperlink, but all you would have to do to use the dark gray background image is remove the active class. If you're not going to use it as a link (to take you to another page), apply the styles to the "li" selector instead of the "a" selector.

Comment: Hi jenhan. If Menu has PageA, PageB, and PageC but is showing PageA, then Menu.PageA does not need to be a link. The working, end result is [HERE](http://www.jp2code.net).