# Slide a background-image behind an image link

Tags: jquery, image, button, background

So, i have this html webpage with a menu. I have coded the menu as a list with 3 links.

The menu consists of Illustrator png images : home, contact, etc. What i want to achieve is that a certain color slides from the left when you hover on the links. This certain color is also an Illustrator image.

I was able to do this (with a tutorial) with a simple   plain text for the menu, the image for the background slide and jQuery: [jQuery buttons](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11998293/buttons/index.html), 
but I want to do this with 2 images.

Am i explaining myself correctly?
How can I attempt to do this?

Comment: Just use a sprite for the background with the two colors, and animate the background position to change the background.

Comment: I know. But in this case i have two images. The button with transparent background and the image that slides from the left behind the transparent button. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure it is, but you probably will have to place another element with overflow hidden behind the button, and slide the image into that element to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with overflow. Could use an img in the link and use the background-image property as the slider?

Comment: IS there way to hide the background image and show it on mouse over?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can achieve this, here are 3.

1) Include the transparent image in your background image sprite. So you're combining both images and using it as a single background image. Then you just position the background image accordingly. If you're not familiar with sprites, here is a post that discusses them: [CSS Sprite Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873323/css-sprite-button)

2) Hard code the image into your link and use css to generate the background color. That way you don't have to use a separate image. For example:
    a:hover { background: #f00; }

3) Hard code the image into your link and use a background image to achieve the hover effect. I don't recommend this because it causes your links to become unsearchable and unselectable.